# c# - Printing the key and value of a dictionary separately

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary containing the key and the values. I want to print to the console the key and the value. But I want to print the key and value separately. y is unique and m is the value assigned to the key.

See here how I have attempted to do it, but I get an error saying

> method, delegate or event is expected

Code:

```
List<int> col = new List<int>();
Dictionary<int, int> dic = new Dictionary<int, int>();
//iterates through min-max
for (int y = 0; y <= 15; y++)
   {   
 int m = 0;
   //iterates through array
      for (int i = 0; i < Arr.Length; i++)
         { 
            //comparisons
              if (y == Arr[i])
              {
                 m++;

               }

           }
 dic.Add(y,m);  
 Console.WriteLine("Number {0} appears {1} times ", y, dic[y]);
```

Comment: I don't get it. What exactly you need? Give some sample input and expected output.

Comment: Your requirements don't make sense, if y is unique then surely it will only ever appear once? Can you provide some sample input and expected output

Comment: @musefan: i guess that the text is just misleading and is not related to the dictionary itself but to the meaning of the dictionary's keys and values.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Yes, I think you may be right. Only thing that makes any sense. It's a mighty tricky question that's for sure

Comment: @musefan Sorry I have added the rest of the code to make it clearer. I want to be able to print the number and then the number of times it appears in the array

Comment: @Tim Schmelter What I'm trying to do is sort the counts in ascending order without messing up what number it's associated with, I was told a dictionary was the way to solve this.

Comment: @Theman: you are not showing and you haven't mentioned that you want to sort something. You're just looping from 0 to 15.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the indexer `dic[something]` operation to get the value for a given key.

```
Dictionary<int, int> dic = new Dictionary<int, int>();
//rest of my code here
{...}
dic.Add(y,m);
Console.WriteLine("Number {0} appears {1} times ", y, dic[y]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly to get the value of a dictionary you use

```
dic[y]
```

I think in your case

```
Console.WriteLine("Number {0} appears {1} times ", y, dic[y]);
```

suffices. As a side note, you cannot search using the value only the key.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Dictionary<int, int> dic = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        //rest of my code here
        int y = 100;
        int m = 200;
        dic.Add(y,m);
        Console.WriteLine("Number {0} appears {1} times ", y, dic[y]);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> entry in dic)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(entry);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to loop from 0 to 15 and print ot how many times another array contains every number (which is a completely different requirement now):

```
for (int y = 0; y <= 15; y++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Number {0} appears {1} times ", y, Arr.Count(i => i == y));       
}
```